# Can we use Azure Key vault to encrypt XML files on local computer?

Tags: c#, xml, azure, azure-keyvault

I have couple of XMLs in my local computer, which I need to encrypt using using Azure key Vault. I need help with this.

I found some documentation on encryption of blob using Azure key. Not sure, whether to follow that or not. I'm completely new to Azure Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would send the files to KeyVault and receive the encrypted files back. You should base64url encode the XML file in order to get a single block of text.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/encrypt/encrypt

Comment: this answer contains a dead link